# An English equivalent of the Japanese idiom "be on dog-monkey terms"

Tags: translation, idiom-request

The Japanese idiom "be on dog-monkey terms" means "be on very bad terms".

Is there an English idiom equivalent to this Japanese idiom?

> Mary: Look! Brian and Kevin are quarreling about a petty thing again.
>
> Susan: They *are on dog-monkey terms*.

**[Edit]** The Japanese idiom in itself does not imply "regular quarrel" or "big difference in personality". For example,

> (1) They *are on dog-monkey terms*, never speaking or making eye contact.

> (2) Judy and Lisa were on very good terms, but now they *are on dog-monkey terms*.

Comment: [Synonyms of 'at daggers drawn' in British English](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/at-daggers-drawn)

Comment: There's no shortage of terms. Can you be more specific (how formal, how polite, how insulting, how cute, and whether it must involve animals.)

Comment: Another possibility here in the UK at least is "They aren't getting on" - which means something like "they don't have a good relationship".

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you, Billy. I am looking for an English idiom that means "have a very bad relationship".

Comment: @StuartF The Japanese idiom can be used in every situation. It is not that I am looking for an English idiom involving animals. (I was looking for one involving animals, but I gave up.)

Comment: Well, maybe "They really aren't getting on" or if it's more permanent "They really don't get on".

Comment: Stronger (informal) : They hate each other's guts.  To hate someone's guts = to utterly despise someone.  Also "They never see eye to eye" - they can never agree.

Comment: @BillyKerr Is it idiomatic to say "They are on non-speaking terms"?

Comment: @Kaguyahime - yes it's perfectly fine, but it's not an idiom. I thought you were looking for an idiom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151025/discussion-between-kaguyahime-and-billy-kerr).

Answer (score 2):

Some English expressions come to mind, but they may not exactly match your Japanese saying like for like.

- They fight like cat and dog (means they constantly fight)
- They are like chalk and cheese (means they are very different people and do not naturally get along)
- They have a love-hate relationship (means they make a volatile relationship which may flit between love and hate)

Comment: I think it's cats and _dogs_.

Comment: @OwenReynolds almost - 'cat and dog' singular. You might be thinking of *raining cats and dogs*.

Comment: to me "like cat and dog" sounds unnatural. I'm not going to be too definite about this but I would instinctively go with "cats and dogs". Maybe it just flows better.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fight%20like%20cats%20and%20dogs#:~:text=idiom,fighting%20like%20cats%20and%20dogs

Comment: @timchessish In Cambridge Dictionary, "fight like cat and dog" is labeled "UK". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fight-like-cats-and-dogs

Comment: @Kaguyahime I'm from the UK, it really doesn't matter, fight like cat and dog, or cats and dogs. Both are acceptable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fight%20like%20cat%20and%20dog

Comment: @Kaguyahime If you look at the link Mari-Lou posted, the plural form is chiefly US. The same dictionary lists the singular use as British. You're right, we'd understand either, but the singular is certainly the idiom I'm used to.

Comment: @Astralbee It seems that "like chalk and cheese" is close in meaning to the Japanese idiom "relationship between water and oil". Thank you very much, Astralbee.

Comment: @Kaguyahime Being "[like oil and water](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/like-oil-and-water)" is also an expression in English.

Answer (score 0):

"They are on dog-monkey terms." seems to mean the same as "They can't stand each other." which is less extreme than "They hate each others guts."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).